# How to send "feedback" to telegrambot using JAVA/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to create a feedback form with android studio I'm quite a beginner but with android studio to make the simple form look it's not that hard what I need now is to send a 'feedback form' to my telegram bot so when a user sends feedback to us, it should be sent to my telegrambot

**values.xml**

```
<string name="feedback"></string>
```

i search on internet very deep got this code

```
var urlString = "https://api.telegram.org/bot%s/sendMessage?chat_id=%s&text=%s"
val apiToken = "my_bot_api_token"
val chatId = "@my_channel_name"
val text = "Hello world!"
urlString = String.format(urlString, apiToken, chatId, text)
val url = URL(urlString)
val conn = url.openConnection()
val inputStream = BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream())
val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
val response = br.readText()
// Do what you want with response
```

But since I'm a newbie in java/kotlin I can't figure out what functions to change

Any help would be great